# Control iPhone music from linux command line

Tags: command-line, iphone

Is this possible?  Could one, for example, send a command to an iPhone which tells it to start playing a certain song?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064967/control-idevice-from-linux-over-usb